# Mapping through state: (TypeError): this.state.[something].map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to map through my state, where I have collected data from an external API.

However, when I do i get this error here:
TypeError: this.state.stocks.map is not a function

I want to render the results to the frontend, through a function so that the site is dynamic to the state.favorites.
Though the console.log(), I can see that the data is stored in the state.

I have found others with a similar issue, but the answers did not work out.

UPDATE:
I have changed the componentDidMount() and it now produces an array. The issue is that I get no render from the renderTableData() functions.

console.log shows this array:

```
0: {symbol: "ARVL", companyName: "Arrival", primaryExchange: "AESMSBCDA)LNKOS/ TLTE(N GAEQLGAR ", calculationPrice: "tops", open: 0, …}
1: {symbol: "TSLA", companyName: "Tesla Inc", primaryExchange: " RNK EAASGTDACLN)LE/OGMELAQSTB (S", calculationPrice: "tops", open: 0, …}
2: {symbol: "AAPL", companyName: "Apple Inc", primaryExchange: "AMTGS/C) AALGDRSTNLEOEL(S BAE NQK", calculationPrice: "tops", open: 0, …}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

This is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './Table.css';


class Table extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
     super(props);
      this.state = {
         favorites: ['aapl', 'arvl', 'tsla'],
         stocks: []
     };
 }

  componentDidMount() {
   this.state.favorites.map((favorites, index) => {
   fetch(`API`)
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then(stockList => {
         const stocksState = this.state.stocks;
         const stockListValObj = stockList;
         console.log(stocksState)
         console.log(stockListValObj)
         this.setState({
            stocks: [
                ... stocksState.concat(stockListValObj)
            ]
          }, () => { console.log(this.state.stocks);});
      })
   })
 }


renderTableData() {
    this.state.stocks.map((stocks, index) => {
      const { companyName, symbol, latestPrice, changePercent, marketCap } = stocks //destructuring
      return (
        <div key={symbol} className='headers'>
          <div className='first-value'>
            <h4>{companyName}</h4>
            <h4 className='symbol'>{symbol}</h4>
          </div>
          <div className='align-right'>
            <h4>{latestPrice}</h4>
          </div>
          <div className='align-right'>
            <h4 className='changePercent'>{changePercent}</h4>
          </div>
          <div className='align-right'>
            <h4>{marketCap}</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
   })
}


   render() {
      return (
         <div className='table'>
            <h1 id='title'>Companies</h1>
            <div className='headers'>
              <h4 className='align-right'></h4>
              <h4 className='align-right'>Price</h4>
              <h4 className='align-right'>+/-</h4>
              <h4 className='align-right'>Market Cap</h4>
            </div>

            <div>
              {this.renderTableData()}
            </div>

         </div>
      )
   }
 }

export default Table;
```

Comment: What exactly does that `console.log(stockList);` print out?

Comment: stockList is not an array

Comment: You do not have any `this.state.map` in code that you provided, instead there is `this.state.[something].map`

Comment: @ulou I have updated the headline.

Comment: @Binne please show the output of `console.log(stockList);`. I assume that isn't an array.

Comment: @MaddyBlacklisted it shows: 
Object Table.jsx:20, 
Object Table.jsx:20, 
Object Table.jsx:20
The 3 objects shows the data pulled from the API.

Comment: Confirm that stock list is an array returned not another type of an object. *Before adding the stcoklist to stock* try something like `stock: Array.isArray(stocklist)?stocklist:[]`. The error above might be caused by the reason that stocklist is not an array

Comment: @DiscoveryCity I tried to add your suggestion like so: `this.setState({ stock: Array.isArray(stockList)?stockList:[] });` It did not work. But I think that you are right about the returned object is not an array.

Comment: @Binne. if it is not an object then instead of assigning directly. try pushing the stocklist instead of reassigning. you can use _push_ to add the stocklist to stock.
Something like `const newObj=this.state.stock.concat(stocklist); //Then you can assign newObj to stock `

Comment: @DiscoveryCity Thanks this helped! See the edited post on how I got this.state.stocks to be an array :)

Comment: add `return` before `this.state.stocks.map`

Comment: You are running your `setState` inside the `then` of a `fetch`, which is inside a `map` of another array. The first thing I'd say is *do not use `map` for side effects*. `map` returns an array. If you're not going to use that array, use `forEach` instead of `map`. Secondly, your state may not contain what you think it should, since both `fetch` and `setState` are asynchronous. It may call them `setState` in order, with enough time between such that the previous state contains the data from the previous `fetch`, but probably not.

Comment: `renderTableData()` does not return anything at the moment.

Comment: @Thomas good catch! It now renders the table! Nice, thanks ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always aim in making single state update, try reducing the state update to single update.

I suggest 2 solution:

1. Move the data fetch section into a separate function, update a temporary array variable return the variable at the end of the execution.

```
  async dataFetch() {
    const sampleData = this.state.stocks || [];
    await this.state.favorites.forEach((favorites, index) => {
      fetch(`API`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((stockList) => {
          sampleData.push(stockList);
          // const stocksState = this.state.stocks;
          // const stockListValObj = stockList;
          // console.log(stocksState);
          // console.log(stockListValObj);
          //  this.setState({
          //     stocks: [
          //         ... stocksState.concat(stockListValObj)
          //     ]
          //   }, () => { console.log(this.state.stocks);});
        });
    });
    return Promise.resolve(sampleData);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.dataFetch().then((stockValues) => {
      this.setState({ stocks: stockValues });
    });
  }
```

2. Use `Promise.all()` this return a single array value which would be easier to update on to the stock state.

Suggestion : When not returning any values from the array try using `Array.forEach` instead of `Array.map`

Return keyword is missing in `renderTableData`

```
renderTableData() {
    this.state.stocks.map((stocks, index) => { ...});
```

to

```
renderTableData() {
   return this.state.stocks.map((stocks, index) => { ...});
```

Comment: I tried your solution, and I like the idea of creating a separate function for the API call. The function works, but it is not stored in the state.stock at componentDidMount.

Comment: Update the sample, verify. 
Overlooked there was a state.stock inside componentDidMount. If the previous data is required, set `state.stock` value to sampleData variable, later update sampleData when proper data is fetched from the API

Comment: So I tried the new version, but the state is not updated. I did try to console.log it, and the forEach returns an array for each of the items in the state.favorites. Each of the arrays do contain the information for all of the items. 
I'm not sure where it goes wrong, but it doesnt transfer the data to the state.

Comment: what is the value of `stockList` returned from the API. Is it array or object?

Comment: return statement is missing in renderTableData()

Comment: [{…}]
(2) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]

I have added the return statement in renderTableData()

Comment: StockList returns an orbject

Comment: Can you also add bind statement in the constructor for renderTableData. `this.renderTableData = this.renderTableData.bind(this)`. Please update the code in the problem statement with latest code, or provide a codepen or codesandbox link to look into the complete code.

Comment: I have made a codepen here: https://codesandbox.io/embed/elastic-kare-xlg4e?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Update the codepen, https://codesandbox.io/embed/wild-fire-deej7 . Replace the API

Comment: This works! Thank you so much for your time and help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that this is happening because on the first render, the map looks into state.stock and it's an empty array. After the first render, the componentDidMount method is called fetching the data.

I would suggest to just wrap the map into a condition. If stock doesn't have any object, then return whatever you wish (null or a loader/spinner for example).

It's enough to add it like this for not returning anything in case the array is empty (it will be filled after the first render, but this is useful as well to return error message in case the fetch fails):

```
this.state.stocks.length > 0 && this.state.stocks.map((stocks, index) => {
```

Comment: Mapping an empty array will just return an empty array, and React accepts arrays in JSX (including empty ones) so that shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: @DBS The console.log shows a json file for each of the elements in the state.favorites.

Comment: I tried the solution proposed by Alex, and it doesnt render anything. I suggest that the state.stock is empty? Or perhaps not valid for using the .map() function.

Comment: can you try with ternary to return something anyway?
`this.state.stocks.length > 0 ? this.state.stocks.map(....) : 'Error'`
does it return the Error or nothing? Also, you can check in the React Dev tools wether the component state is changing, or if you are fetching real data, the network tab should have a get request.

Comment: @Alex I'm not sure on how to do it. I added the new line of code at the beginning, and the `: 'Error'` at the end, right before the last curly bracket. I'm not getting any error nor is it rendering any thing. I have updated the post, as I believe my state.stocks is an array now.